# W3 Total Cache What do I need to do when I update style.css?

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

A client asked me to edited minor details on his Wordpress website. I did and I also add/edit stuff in style.css. However, the changes I've made in style.css wasn't showing up. After debugging, I found out that it's because of the Wordpress plugin W3 Total Cache that this website was using. I found out that W3 Total Cache's Minify was used to minify and convert the style.css into another file without line breaks, etc or something like that.

Therefore, what steps do I need to take to make the changes I've added to style.css to show up? I'm not really familiar with W3 Total Cache. Do I wait for the minify to automatically update the style.css, search for that minify css stylesheet to make edits in, or is there anything I can do to make the changes show up?

Answer (score 1):

Cache will eventually automatically update itself. However, if you want to trigger it manually you simply need to find the `empty cache` button in the appropriate section. Pressing it will re-generate the cache with updated assets.

In the case of W3TC, you have the option of emptying all caches at once:

[image]

Or navigating into **Performance > General** Settings and emptying a specific cache on it's own:

[image]

Comment: What about the CSS section in the Minify menu? There's a button that say "Save Settings & Purge Caches". Will that work also similar to "empty cache" button?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: I tried to click on "empty cache" button and "Save Settings & Purge Caches" button but it didn't work. I found out that it only works if I click on "Manual" in Minify mode. But after I made changes and then switch back to "Auto", it went back to previous changes!!